# Converting any RDF serialization into RDF/XML

Tags: type-conversion, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf, n3

I have seen some examples where there is a possibility to convert known serializations in RDF/XML but when the input format (e.g. XML/Turtle/N3) is not known, is there any way of achieving the conversion?

I am writing a tool that receives RDF in different serializations (Turtle/xml/n3) but when I call

```
 model.read(InputStream in, "", "")
```

method of `Model` Class from Jena, there are exceptions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?  For example: 1) Sample input RDF, 2) how the result RDF looks, and 3) most important - what errors are you getting.  Sample code would be nice, too :)

Comment: @paulsm4 
Some typical errors/exceptions: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog & java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/TokenStream (Even though the jar is inside the lib & Classpath).
1) My incoming messages from JMS can be any RDF (XML, N3, Turtle). I need to convert any type of incoming messages to RDF/XML in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an input stream - you have to tell it the format.  `model.read(in, base, "TURTLE")`.  It does not sniff the stream.  You could do a sequence of model.read each inside a try-catch until one does not cause an exception.

Comment: This solution from AndyS seems to work, but what are the compromises in terms of performance. E.g. if i have a list of lang (Turtle, XML, N3) & i iterate over it to create the model each time unless i get one.